# Sum of opportunity amount on account records

Tags: opportunity, formula-field, account, roll-up-summary, sales

I have one field that calculates last year's sum of donation amount using a managed package. My requirement is to create a new field on Account object to calculate sum of total opportunity amount from today to past 12 months. I tried to create a roll up summary field but not sure how to handle date requirement.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with a 'past 12 months' criteria. How is this number used?  is it just in reports? or do you specifically need it shown in the UI?

Comment: @NickCook Need to specifically show in the UI. Any other recommendations to achieve this?

Comment: I'll refrain from voting on this duplicate but I think it's not a great "master" question because one of the answers is incorrect and the other is not very detailed.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) three ways to implement time-bounded roll-up summary fields. However, you cannot do it using only native Roll-Up Summary fields - they only recalculate on trigger events, and won't update based on the passage of time.

1. [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). You can define a rollup that includes time-based criteria, like `CloseDate = LAST_12_MONTHS`. Then you can configure the rollup to run both in real-time mode (for intraday changes) and in a scheduled batch on the 1st of each month, ensuring your data is always up to date.
2. Time-Based Workflows plus native Roll-Up Summary Fields. This is a bit more complex and situation-dependent. In quick summary, you can use Time-Based Actions in either Workflow or Process Builder that are configured to execute at the points when the Date field on your object (here, Opportunity.Close Date) enters and leaves the date range that your rollup defines. Your workflow actions can update a field ("Active", say, or "Summarized") to provide the triggered event that the native Roll-Up Summary Field needs to execute. Then, your Roll-Up Summary is written with criteria against the "Summarized" field, rather than any explicit date criteria.

   There are some challenges to this approach - it's complex and can be tricky to understand, and you must be aware of the limits on [how Salesforce processes time-based actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=5). Notable, Salesforce will process only 1,000 time triggers per hour, so if your volume is substantially greater than that, you may observe a lot of lag in your data updates.
3. Scheduled Apex. You can write a Scheduled Apex or Scheduled Batch class and arrange for it to execute every day or every first of the month, and have that class query child objects, recalculate totals, and update the parent objects. Optionally, you can pair this functionality with a trigger for real-time intraday or intramonth updates.

   Scheduled Apex is the most engineering-intensive approach.

I would recommend applying DLRS if you are able to fit your use case into its capabilities.